# Is there an easier way to specify this?

Tags: alloy

As in the following code, is there any way to make macros for the expressions `NP + NF2 + NF1 + NT + NR` and `AnonActive + Aactive + AsetTurn + Astart + Acrit + Acheck + APF2 + APF1 + ATP + ATR + AF2R + AF1R`, so that I can refer to them later by name rather than writing the expressions out directly?

```
sig NP{}
sig NF2{}
sig NF1{}
sig NT{}
sig NR{}

sig AnonActive{src:one NP, trg:one NP}
sig Aactive{src:one NP, trg:one NP}
sig AsetTurn{src:one NP, trg:one NP}
sig Astart{src:one NP, trg:one NP}
sig Acrit{src:one NP, trg:one NP}
sig Acheck{src:one NP, trg:one NP}
sig APF2{src:one NP, trg:one NF2}
sig APF1{src:one NP, trg:one NF1}
sig ATP{src:one NT, trg:one NP}
sig ATR{src:one NT, trg:one NR}
sig AF2R{src:one NF2, trg:one NR}
sig AF1R{src:one NF1, trg:one NR}

sig Graph{nodes:set NP+NF2+NF1+NT+NR, 
          arrows:set AnonActive + Aactive + AsetTurn + Astart 
                     + Acrit + Acheck + APF2 + APF1 + ATP + ATR 
                     + AF2R + AF1R}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to declare abstract signatures `Node` and `Arrow`, and declare each of your existing signatures as extending one or the other of them.

```
abstract sig Node {}
sig NP extends Node {}
sig NF2 extends Node {}
...
```

Since all your arrows have the same relations, the relations can be declared in the Arrow sig; the restrictions on the kinds of nodes allowed as source and target can be given using signature facts, as for example:

```
abstract sig Arrow {
  src:  one Node,
  trg:  one Node
}
sig AnonActive extends Arrow {}{
  one + trg in NP
}
...
sig AF1R extends Arrow {}{
  src in NF1
  trg in NR
}
```

Now the declaration of Graph is quite simple (and, at least to some eyes, perhaps a bit clearer):

```
sig Graph {
  nodes: set Node,
  arrows: set Arrow 
}
```

Another approach (less good in the case shown, I think, but useful in cases where the first approach cannot be applied) would be to define functions with the appropriate names:

```
fun Node : set univ {
  NP + NF2 + NF1 + NT + NR
}
fun Arrow : set univ {
  AnonActive + Aactive + AsetTurn + Astart 
  + Acrit + Acheck + APF2 + APF1 + ATP + ATR 
  + AF2R + AF1R
}
```

N.B. I have not checked these for syntax errors ...